# how to get specific data from ParseObject

Tags: java, android, android-studio, parse-platform

I have class name ("RHospital") 
and I search in column ("appointDate") for a list of the dates , but what I get is the Full ParseObject because I write in the query Method ParseObject , However I want only the date in ("appointDate") 
so How can I retrieve it ?

my problem is that I don't know how to do search of list of specific data in Parse class 
this is a screen shot of the data in parse 
[image]

and this is mycode

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(2015, 8, 12, 0, 0, 0);
        Calendar sswal = Calendar.getInstance();
        sswal.set(2015, 8, 12, 23, 30, 0);
        Date dd = cal.getTime();
        Date mok =sswal.getTime();
        final ParseObject[] most = new ParseObject[15];
        Date moste[]=new Date[15];

  ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("RHospital");
    query.selectKeys(Arrays.asList("appointDate"));
    query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("appointDate", dd);
    query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("appointDate", mok);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, com.parse.ParseException e) {
            if (list == null) {
                Log.d("score", "The getFirst request failed.");
            } else {
                mStatus = list;

               for (ParseObject Dated: list){
                    post =Dated.getParseObject("appointDate");
                    Log.d("appointDate", "retrieved a related date");
                }

            }
        }

    });
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to get date:

```
Date post =Dated.getDate("appointDate");
```